# string to float function error using csv.dictreader

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the following 2-row csv file as an inital test..

```
milk_price_per_cup,cream_price_per_cup,sugar_price_per_cup,vanilla_extract_price_per_cup,
```

0.70,1.65,1.0,30,

Then trying to run the following code:

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("ingredient_prices.csv"))

milk_price = None
cream_price = None
sugar_price = None
vanilla_price = None


for row in input_file:
    milk_price = float(row["milk_price_per_cup"])
    cream_price = row["cream_price_per_cup"]
    sugar_price = row["sugar_price_per_cup"]
    vanilla_price = row["vanilla_extract_price_per_cup"]  


    print "The milk price is %d, the cream price is %s, the sugar price is %s, and the vanilla price is %s." % (milk_price, cream_price, sugar_price, vanilla_price)
```

Unfortunately the output for the milk price is NOT a float... it comes out as just 0 instead of 0.7....  whats going on here?  Using Python 2.7.6

Comment: Use `str.format`, `"The milk price is {}, the cream price is {}, the sugar price is {}, and the vanilla price is {}.".format(milk_price, cream_price, sugar_price, vanilla_price)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` in string formatting is for integer decimal. If you wan float, you should be using `%f`

Read more on [string formatting options here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

Comment: Or just `%s`. Or, if you don't want to learn printf-style formatting, use `str.format`.